# Como imprimir los elementos de una lista que están dentro de una tupla. Python

Tags: python

Tengo la siguiente tupla en python

```
(['A','H','L','O'] , [['A','F'],['H','S'],['L','L'],['O','W']] )
```

Donde la primera parte de la tupla es:

```
['A','H','L','O']
```

y la segunda parte es

```
['A','F'],['H','S'],['L','L'],['O','W']
```

Como puedo imprimir los elementos de la segunda parte en una sola linea. De esta forma:

```
AFHSLLOW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=(['A','H','L','O'] , [['A','F'],['H','S'],['L','L'],['O','W']] ) #la tupla con las listas
c='' #variable con una cadena vacia
for x in a[1] : #ciclo for  que recorre la lista pocicionada en el indice 1(uno de la tupla)
  c = c+''.join(x) # metodo join para concatenar cadenas recibe x y se suma a la variable c

print c #se imprime la cadena concatenada
```

suerte con lo que sea que estas intentando

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcionó. Se trata de un sistema criptografico :)

Answer (score 1):

Para que te salga todo junto puedes anidar dos ciclos for

```
cadena = (['A','H','L','O'] , [['A','F'],['H','S'],['L','L'],['O','W']])
salida = ''
for sub1 in cadena[1]:
      for sub2 in sub1:
            salida += sub2
print salida
```

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar:

```
salida = ''.join(''.join(letra) for letra in a[1])
```